# Could we simplify the log determinant's concavity proof?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, determinant

The function $f(X) \Rightarrow \log \det X$ is concave as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192329/log-determinant-concavity-proof).
However, I was wondering if we could simplify the proof suggested.

When we compute : $g(t) = \log\det(Z + tV)$, why not just saying that:

$$\begin{aligned}
g(t) &=
\log\det(Z)(I+tZ^{-1}V) \\
&= \sum_i \log(1+t\lambda_i). + \log\det Z
\end{aligned}$$
with $(\lambda_i)$ the eigenvalues of $Z^{-1}V$?

Comment: Are your matrices positive semidefinite or something? And yes, I agree that the introduction of $Z^{1/2}$ is unneeded.

Comment: OK thanks. I think that the problem is not defined if the matrices are not positive definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we can not simplify the proof. Indeed, $Z^{-1}V$ is not [necessarily symmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874469/symmetric-matrix-multiplication), and thus, the decomposition to the eigenvalues is not guaranteed.

This explains the use of the trick with $Z^{1/2}$